# Instagram API - FACEBOOK_PLACES_ID

Tags: instagram

I wrote a mini instagram wordpress plugin for my cafe's website that shows the photos taken there on our homepage. You can see it in action here: dem-istanbul.com

However, since instagram now uses facebook places instead of foursquare, the location id I'm using is outdated, plus I want to add a second place as we have opened a new branch. I've been using this code to list the photos:

```
$result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/83910054/media/recent/?access_token={$accessToken}&count=8");
```

However, when I want to add a second location, I am unable to find the location-id as it now fetches data from facebook places. This value had newly been added to the Instagram API, however I'm at a loss on using it:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/search?lat=48.858844&lng=2.294351&access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

Search for a location by geographic coordinate.

PARAMETERS:

- `DISTANCE`   Default is 1000m (distance=1000), max distance is 5000.
- `FACEBOOK_PLACES_ID` Returns a location mapped off of a Facebook places id. If used, a Foursquare id and lat, lng are not required.
- `FOURSQUARE_ID`  Returns a location mapped off of a foursquare v1 api location id. If used, you are not required to use lat and lng. Note that this method is deprecated; you should use the new foursquare IDs with V2 of their API.
- `LAT`    Latitude of the center search coordinate. If used, lng is required.
- `LNG`    Longitude of the center search coordinate. If used, lat is required.
  FOURSQUARE_V2_ID    Returns a location mapped off of a foursquare v2 api location id. If used, you are not required to use lat and lng.

From what I understand, I should now be able to use facebook places id to list images, but I'm not sure where to get it.

Sorry if that sounds complicated, but I'll be very happy if anyone can help me with this. Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find your location facebook place id, foursquare id or by geographic coordinate.
Your second cafe is probably dem bebek. You can get it's () id via http://graph.facebook.com/DemBebek .
By the way you can get your second cafe's medias via https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/385502821/media/recent